# Friendly disconnect ssh on shutdown?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've recently switched from Raspbian Jessie (that has a full UI) and Jessie-Lite (which is lean and CLI only). I connect via ssh, and have been messing with configuration and restarting my Raspberry Pi a lot. With full Jessie, I could send `sudo shutdown -r now` and my ssh connection (from OSX Sierra) would get a signal that it was being disconnected and close on the client end.

Then I switched to Jessie-Lite and the same thing (`sudo reboot` does this also) will just make ssh hang, eventually after a long time give the me ability to Ctrl-C where it gives me a broken pipe message. I didn't even realize the behavior was due to something extra or a configuration! But now it's really annoying and if I don't want to wait I have to close out my terminal.

What's the magic sauce? What am I missing and how can I install or configure it to get the friendly disconnected behavior back?

(note - my transition also included moving from kernel 4.9 to 4.4)

Comment: Seems to be similar problem like the one, that has solution right here: https://serverfault.com/questions/706475/ssh-sessions-hang-on-shutdown-reboot/706494#706494

Comment: Glad to help you, and props for making fine answer from the suggestion I've made :)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @DevilaN for pointing me [to this answer to a similar problem](https://serverfault.com/a/706494)! That started me on the right track. Here's some more information for those landing here for help.

The 'missing sauce' was a SIGTERM signal, this keeps my ssh client from hanging, and instead indicates it should close. It does so with this message:

```
Connection to 192.168.0.99 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.0.99 closed.
```

SIGTERM is a termination notice. In order to send it, a more flexible login manager needs to be installed over the vanilla system that Jessie Lite came with. This is installed with the `systemd-logind` package, which in turn can be managed with `loginctl`. `systemd-logind` is used to respond to sleep hardware switches, can let other applications interrupt the shutdown process, and helps with multi-user sessions including user connected services. It's not hard to see why a UI distribution of Linux like Raspbian Jessie would choose to use it.

Also needed is `dbus` which is used for message distribution, such as handling the SIGTERM message, and helps with session level logins for multiple users.

As stated in the other answer, a one liner to enable this friendly message on shutdown is:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-systemd dbus
```

If anybody can to expand on (or correct!) any of this information, please do!